# define a text object as the boundary of two marks

Tags: custom-text-object

Is there a way to turn the "region bounded by two specific marks" into a text object similar to `aw` or `ap`?

I've been messing around with `vi` and found it convenient to use `a` and `b`. and define a region and to define commands that act on the region bounded by `a` and `b`.

It would be nice to be able to expose a text object for this purpose in vim.

---

I have the following bindings in `vi` for emulating something kind of like visual mode. I have some macros that set `a` and `b` to the boundaries of an interesting region. And another set of macros for manipulating the region bounded by `a` and `b`.

It's nice to be able to pick whether I want a linewise selection or not after setting the marks.

`^A` and `^P` are literal control characters, in this case they set the mark `a` to the beginning of the buffer or paragraph and `b` to the end.

```
map ^A 1GmaGmb
map ^P }mb{jmak}
```

And other macros that do stuff to the region like indent it and dedent it.

```
map \. mp'a>'b`p
map \, mp'a<'b`p
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example for a custom text object working with the marks `a` and `b`.

```
" char-wise 
onoremap am :<c-u>execute 'normal `av`b'<cr>
xnoremap am :<c-u>execute 'normal `av`b'<cr>
" line-wise
onoremap aM :<c-u>execute 'normal `aV`b'<cr>
xnoremap aM :<c-u>execute 'normal `aV`b'<cr>
```

To copy the characters between the marks `a` and `b` hit `yam`. To copy the lines between `a` and `b` hit `yaM`. You can use it with other commands., like `=am` to format the lines between marks `a` and `b`.

See `:help :map-modes` and `:help omap-info`.

Notes:

- This moves the cursor. After it hit <kbd>Ctrl-O</kbd> twice to get back to your initial cursor position.
- This changes the visual selection. If you used `yam` and hit `gv` afterwards, the visual selection is mark `a` to `b`.

---

If you want to work with any mark, you could try this:

```
onoremap <silent> am :<c-u>execute 'normal `'. nr2char(getchar()) . 'v`' . nr2char(getchar())<cr>
xnoremap <silent> am :<c-u>execute 'normal `'. nr2char(getchar()) . 'v`' . nr2char(getchar())<cr>
onoremap <silent> aM :<c-u>execute 'normal `'. nr2char(getchar()) . 'V`' . nr2char(getchar())<cr>
xnoremap <silent> aM :<c-u>execute 'normal `'. nr2char(getchar()) . 'V`' . nr2char(getchar())<cr>
```

Now you need to give the marks. Like `yamab` copies the range of the marks `a` and `b`, while `yamxy` uses the marks `x` and `y`. If you only want the line of the mark `a` copied, you could use `yaMaa`.

Be careful with upper case marks here. Upper case marks might change the buffer.
Assuming mark `A` is in another buffer, the command `yamAb` will switch to the buffer of the mark `A` and will copy to mark `b` in that buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like the following. **There might be a lot of corner cases**, but it's a start:

```
for s:nr1 in range(97, 122)
    for s:nr2 in range(97, 122)
        let s:char1 = nr2char(s:nr1)
        let s:char2 = nr2char(s:nr2)
        execute 'xnoremap i'.s:char1.s:char2.' :<C-u>normal! `'.s:char1.'v`'.s:char2.'<CR>'
        execute 'onoremap i'.s:char1.s:char2.' :normal vi'.s:char1.s:char2.'<CR>'
    endfor
endfor
```

I used `range(97, 122)` to get a list of numbers from 97 to 122 (see `:h range()` and these represent the ASCII values of characters `a` to `z` which could be converted to characters with `:h nr2char()`. So, if you want uppercase letter marks, you can edit the list range yourself.